# [Vue warn]: Property or method "v" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

this is my component.
`el.focus()` does works when it is inserted, but i got `[Vue warn]: Property or method "v" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render` on the console.
How to remove the warn?

```js
<script>
  export default {
    directives: {
      focus: {
        inserted (el) {
          el.focus()
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```css
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
  input
    width: 300px
    height: 30px
    border: 1px solid #000
</style>

<template lang="jade">
  div
    input(v-focus)
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you pass an empty attribute to jade, as far as I know, what it interprets, in plain HTML, is `attribute="attribute"`. The actual HTML in your case is `v-focus="v-focus"`, which vue interprets as an expression using a property, `v`, that doesn't exist.

You could try `input(v-focus="true")` as it doesn't really matter the value passed to that directive.

Comment: I print the `binding` argument in the `inserted` function.
Then I find:
when my code is `input(v-focus)`, binding.expression is `v-focus`.
when my code is `input(v-focus)`, binding has no `expression` property, and the warn is disappeared